# How to integrate flash file in an android page?

Tags: android, flash, webview, integrate

I have been developing an android app with games created from flash.
I have researched and found out that it can be possible to integrate the swf file in the android by copying it to the assets folder and placing the url path in a webview. I tried it and no errors were found except when I run it to the emulator, the output was just a plain white screen.

here is the code I used:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
```

public class SWFFileActivity extends Activity {
       private WebView mWebView;

```
@Override  
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_swffile);
    mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);   
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/fingerspell");


    }
```

}

when I try to put the .swf extention in the url, "Web page not found" message displays on the white screen.

my project's SDK is 18.

I can't figure out what the problem is.
Is there any other way to integrate swf files in an android project?
Is this really possible?

Comment: The problem is Flash Plugin no longer supported since Android version 4 onwards (not in webview or web browser). Nowadays the only way to load SWF is to use the **[Flash program](http://www.adobe.com/products/animate.html)** itself to create your APK in the first place, in turn that app can have AS3 code to embed or load the SWF you are trying to load now. Otherwise no other option. Finally you can try **FFMpeg** for Android SDK to see if it will render SWF files